# Can I hide the 'highchart.com' text from my angular application?

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart

I want to use highchart for free in my angular application. It is just a simple gantt chart. Here is the [Demo on Staclblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

How can I remove the text highlighted for free?

If not, any other ways to plot a gantt chart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be removed using credits option in your chart settings.
(as wrote in the api documentation https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits)

```
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    // some code
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    // some code
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. So it is free to use without any trouble? They sell their library.

Comment: @Hello read their TOS. this option offered officially in their API with no hacks.